# Play Framework: IntegrationSpec ignoring configuration provided to FakeApplication when running play test

Tags: unit-testing, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Play 2.2 and Specs2 and having the following test

```
  import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
  import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner

  import play.api.test.Helpers.running
  import play.api.test.{FakeApplication, TestBrowser, TestServer}
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
  import org.fluentlenium.core.domain.{FluentList, FluentWebElement}
  import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

  "Application" should {
    "work from within a browser" in {
      running(TestServer(port, application = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map("configParam.value" -> 2)), classOf[FirefoxDriver]) {
      .....
      }
    }
  }
```

`configParam.value` is being accessed the following way in the application

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.Play._
import play.api.libs.ws.Response
import play.api.libs.json.JsObject

object Configuration {
   val configParamValue = current.configuration.getString("configParam.value").get
}
```

When running `play test` the `configParam.value` being used is the one from `application.conf` instead of the one passed in `FakeApplication`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: More detail would be nice. Versions of Play and Specs2 you're using etc. Also the Imports for the classes you're using here.

Comment: I have added version and import statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably with the `Map` passed to `additionalConfiguration`.

You're passing an `Int` and trying to get a String with "getString"

Try changing to this:

```
running(TestServer(port, application = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map("configParam.value" -> "2")), classOf[FirefoxDriver]) {
```

Notice the `"` around the `2`.